# Translate Objective-C to Xamarin - Blur Image

Tags: objective-c, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm trying to create a blur effect in an iOS Xamarin project and I found an example article that has a very good explanation and seems to be what I want to do but it is written in Objective-C.  I know there are probably a thousand ways to do this but I was hoping someone could help me translate this one line from the article so I can move forward because I'm stuck.  The line is:

```
[NSValue valueWithBytes:&transform objCType:@encode(CGAffineTransform)]
```

I'm not 100% sure what this line does and NSValue doesn't seem to have a ValueWithBytes method so I think I'm missing something here.

The full snippet is:

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
CIFilter *clampFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIAffineClamp"];
[clampFilter setValue:inputImage forKey:@"inputImage"];
[clampFilter setValue:[NSValue valueWithBytes:&transform objCType:@encode(CGAffineTransform)] forKey:@"inputTransform"];
```

If you want to review the code from the article it is listed [here (4. Blurring the Snapshot - Option 1: Core Image)](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/adding-blur-effects-on-ios--cms-21488).

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in iOS 8, you can apply a [blur effect](http://blog.xamarin.com/adding-view-effects-in-ios-8/) to a View like this

```
var blur = UIBlurEffect.FromStyle (UIBlurEffectStyle.Light);
var blurView = new UIVisualEffectView (blur) {
  Frame = new RectangleF (0, 0, imageView.Frame.Width, 400)
};
View.Add (blurView);
```

Xamarin also has a [sample](http://developer.xamarin.com/samples/UIImageEffects/) showing how to use CoreImage to apply effects, including blur.

Comment: Hi Jason - This worked perfect and was a lot easier.  Thanks!

Comment: Do you also know a solution for iOS 7?